# What can I store in transactions?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have several entities, which I must store in transactions. Every entity has its own required params, will be any problems with storing them? I apologize in advance, if the question is stupid), I just started learning fabric.

Comment: this question is not stupid, but it is a bit too broad. What exactly are you asking?

Comment: @christo4ferris, my question is, will I be able to store data with different params. For example, I have entity "car", car has required param "number of wheels" and entity "human", with required param "number of legs". So, car doesn't have legs, and human doesn't have wheels, how I will store them? In different tables in DB (thanks for info about DB Bassel Kh), or in 1 table but without required params and params for every entity will be in one table? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values are saved in DB as key/value pair, the value can be JSON object.
Which means that you can pass array of:
[Param name, param type, param value]
The json object which takes an array of the above dynamic structure can model anything, so it meets your requirement.

I hope if i could answer your question

Comment: dear, you need to read how to deal with blockchain and blockchain database first, there is no such relational DB, please check the following link: https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.1/couchdb_as_state_database.html?highlight=database#

Comment: @Baseel Kh, thank you, I didn't understand your answer first)